# Service parameters not detected when restarted

Tags: windows, service

Ok, I have a simple console application that runs as a service, automatically starting up...
In the main entry point of this application I have this (pseudo code):

```
if ParamStr(1) = '-service' then
    begin
       WriteDebugFile('service openned!', 'C:\Debug.txt')
    end
```

The services.msc show me this file path:

> C:\ProgramData\My Service\commandline.exe -service

and I tried too:

> "C:\ProgramData\My Service\commandline.exe" -service

If I Start/Stop the service from the services.msc, I keep getting the Debug.txt lines added, this means that the console application detected -service as a parameter. But if I logoff/logon or restart Windows, I just don't get anything on the Debug.txt file. The service runs, appears as running, the process is created, but looks like it runs without the parameter '-service'. What is happening here?